# Listview based on a Map<String, Integer> Object

Tags: java, android, listview

Is it possible to create a ListView that uses a map object of the form: Map?

In my Map object I store a list of UserNames(String) and the user's on-line status(Integer). So you get something like this:

```java
{User1=0, User2=1, User3=1, User4=1, 5=1}
```

What I want to do is have a ListView with all the users and have something to identify if a user is on-line, based on the user's on-line status. For example if a user is on-line then the background of that row will have a different background. Or even something as simple as having a text of "ON" or "OFF" before every user's name. It's not really important to me the way the on/off-line users will be distinguished, just to be able to distinguish them in some way.

I'd love if you could give me some pointers, if this can be done, or if it is better to use some other way.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose you have an map in which all the data are stored say map, then make customListAdapter use the above links in comments if you dont know how to make customadapter for listview and inside custom adapter check

```
if(map.containsValue(User1))
                            {
                                changebackground of listview
                            }
```